# Selenium to retrieve value from DIV element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am working on a webScraper project so I came across many applicaitons like pascal and Jsoup.  Now I am working on Selenium , in which I have no experience.
I am struggling a lot to retrive a text of the div item.

Example:
Current `HTML` has `Div` like this:

```
<div id="j_dfg:fdfhg2:2:fasd" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget info-tooltip">
Working Fine
</div>
```

Then I need my output to be (Expected Output):

> Working Fine

Code Used to retrive the Expected output:

```
WebElement element = firefoxDriver.findElement(By.id("j_dfg:fdfhg2:2:fasd"));
String testi = element.toString();
System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa: "+testi);
```

Actual OutPut:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaa: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on ANY
> (744b2871-585c-462f-adac-b4xxxx)] -> id: j_dfg:fdfhg2:2:fasd]

Please help me to get the expected output.

Comment: If I use:  
element.toString().getText().toString()
It returns null.

Comment: No it doesn't, checkout again because getText() is the right way.

Comment: @DineshKumar : I've posted my answer. You do not need to do `toString()` as you can get it from getText() method. `element.toString()` gives you WebElement as string, not an actual text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract text, you need to use `getText()` method in following way :

```
String testi = element.getText();
```

Comment: You code works for a different div , but it is not working for the DIV id reference which i mentioned in my code. Is my code valid ?

Comment: different div means? As id is unique in each page, you can't have multiple div with same id.

Comment: Or at least, you're not supposed to have multiple divs with the same id, but it happens.

Comment: Hmm !!! You can use xpath if div position do not change. Again, I suggest you to ensure about the id. Unique Id is what I prefer if you have.